# I know "of" sounds like "ov". Does "I've" sound like "If"?

Tags: pronunciation, contractions, speech

I was studying connected speech and I read when we say for example

> I've finished my homework

we pronounce the *'ve* and *f* in *finished* as only one sound.

Is it only in this case or whenever I use this contraction?

Comment: Yeah, they run together. The general rule is that a cluster of consonants can be either all voiced or all voiceless, but switching voicing on or off during a cluster pronunciation requires an independent neural signal to the larynx, timed with millisecond precision. It's not impossible, but it's a lot of trouble when it isn't necessary, and it's slower. Most importantly, precise articulation calls attention to itself when it isn't obviously required by the context, and that's the last thing one normally wants when talking.

Comment: I'm not sure mine do. The *ve* is voiced and the *f* is not. I would suggest that's true of most BrE speakers.

Comment: Thinking about how I pronounce the two phrases _I finished_ and _I've finished_, my impression is that the /f/ is longer in the second than the first. Rather like the /s/ at the end of "5/6" _five sixths_ is long: /fayv'sɪkss/, because of the deleted /θ/. This is known as "compensatory lengthening", which is also invoked to account for French accent marks in an ancient case of lengthening.

Comment: What @John said. To me it seems "awkward" to extend the voiced ***v*** in *"I want to know if **we've finished**"* (Can we stop now?), as opposed to *"I want to know if **we finished**"* (Did we succeed?). I think I just slightly exaggerate (or *lengthen*) the /f/ in the first version, whilst discarding the /v/ completely.

Comment: Being a UK speaker I decided to test this out and from what I hear "I'f" and "I've" are different. It is very slight but I can not only feel my mouth and throat voice differently but I can hear a definite difference between the two. I would imagine that, in quick discussion, a non-native English person may think they are the same, however, from my own experimentation I do not believe they are. For one "I've" seems to have a less abrupt ending than "I'f"; it has a prolonged "e" too.

Comment: Actually I coudn't grasp my answer through your comments. I guess that's why you've commented instead answering. Anyway by listening online translators it seems "I've" sounds really like "I've".

Comment: @Sammaye If it's got a prolonged _e_, then you're saying it wrong. The _e_ is purely orthographic; it has no counterpart in the pronunciation at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well if that's the case then everyone I know in the UK (of which I have lived my entire life in) says it wrong too

Comment: @Sammaye So everyone you know pronounces _I’ve_ and _IV_ (as in ‘intravenous’) the same? A prolonged /e/ is [i:], as in ‘see’, and I have never, ever in my entire life heard a single native English speaker pronounce that sound in _I’ve_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I do not remember comparatively stating that "see" and "I've" sound the same. There are many forms of a prolonged "e", "see" is double prolonged whereas "I've" seems to have a distinct prolonged "e" on the end which makes it different to "I'f" which is abrupt without the "e"

Comment: @Sammaye There are different degrees of vowel length and prolonging. They all require that the vowel be present, though. _I’ve_ is pronounced [aiv] and doesn't have an /e/ to prolong at all. If any vowel is lengthened, it is the /i/ (that is, the [ai]). This is in fact the case and perfectly regular, since vowels are longer before voiced consonants than before voiceless ones in English.

Comment: I know that my 'I've' sounds like the 'ife' in 'life' but I have no idea how widespread that is.

Comment: @pavja2 you from?

Comment: @IWannaKnow Southeast USA

Comment: A title change would be helpful to not indicate it would literally change the vowel sound from (aɪ) to (ɪ). Something like Would *I've* ever rhyme with *Knife*

Answer (score 1):

As an American English speaker, I would say the words run together of course, but there is still a "v" (lips vibrating) sound followed by a propulsion of air "F". I don't completely eliminate the v sound and say "I finished." It would be a subtle difference, but I would pronounce "I finished" and "I've finished" just slightly differently.

Comment: /v/ and /f/ are the same sound, differing only in whether the vocal cords are moving (voicing). Both are labiodental fricatives (lower lip pressed lightly against edge of upper incisors, with light air pressure escaping. What happens in American English _I've finished_ is that the vocal cords are turned off somewhere after the initial /ay/, which may or may not include a portion of the labiodental fricative that follows, which may or may not be audible as a separate /v/ preceding the /f/. The faster the speech, the less likely it is.

Answer (score 0):

No, *I've* never sounds like *If*, not even in this contraction.

However, the contraction does make the *v* sound disappear or melt together with the following *f*, just like a *d* does when followed by a *t*:

```
I'd take it.
```

and more generally, when a "soft" consonant is followed by its "hard" counterpart:

```
web project
bedtime
fog computing
give feedback
quiz star
```